# Compiling runwhen - scan_uint undefined?

Tags: linux, build, compilation, debian, undefined-reference

Recently I tried to build runwhen under a local home/test server with Debian 7 (Wheezy). Googling didn’t do the trick, so I hope I’ll find some nice person pointing me to the right direction here. I got the skalibs package from Laurent Bercot and it all seems to build successfully - except rw-match.

This is the output when i run package/install, as described at http://code.dogmap.org/runwhen/

```
Creating directories

Making compile/host/rw-match
./compile/host/rw-match.o: In function `main':
rw-match.c:(.text.startup+0x13e): undefined reference to `scan_uint'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The following files were not made successfully:
command/rw-match
```

I’m using

- runwhen-2012.07.02.tar.bz2
- skalibs-1.4.2.tar.gz

I guess it's a missing package or library but I didn't found anything useful.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple but not well documented outside of a bunch of mailing lists. 'scan_uint' has been renamed to 'uint_scan' in the recent release of skalibs. Just rename every single instance of 'scan_uint' to 'uint_scan' in rw-match.c and everything compiles nicely.

Comment: Wow, that was quite simple. It's only one instance, so this was pretty easy and now it compiles correctly. Thank you very much!